# Javamail, get message body

Tags: java, message, jakarta-mail

I have the following problem: my email client, using Javamail, can get all the parts of the emails just like sentdate, subject, from, to etc., but I cannot figure it out how to get the body of the message.

I already tried getContent() function but it does not give me the required texts.

Any help will be great.

Thanks, Hectai

Comment: could you put your code please!!

Comment: What are 'the required texts'?

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you could post your code.

I don't know if this is what you are expecting, but "getContent()" doesn't necessarily return a String with the message in it.

Look at the JavaDocs [here](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent()) - it returns an Object.

This might be a String, or a Multipart, or it might be an InputStream. It all depends upon the email message.

I'd suggest trying to print out the type of the Object that getContent() is returning.

Also, please have a read through the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You find a comprehensive introduction how to use the API here [Fundamentals of the JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html) which provides many examples as code snippets.

Comment: FYI: the link is broken. Here's something else you might try: https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/j-javamail/j-javamail-ltr.pdf